# fit an image in a div where the image size varies

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to fit custom size images into a div ,but the images not aligning within the div.I want the alignment like the image in screenshot 1.Please tell me where i'm wrong.

This is a test project actually,i have uploaded the files to the site .You can find it @ http://estoreproj.xyz/sony.aspx

I want it to look alligned like the products in the samsung page which is under categories as dropdown.

here's the JSFiddle---->>> https://jsfiddle.net/b160aj5m/

The screenshots ,css and code are below

Screenshots:
[screenshot1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rz21g.png)
[screenshot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/slaex.jpg)

```
.product{
display: block;
float:left;
margin: 1% 0 1% 1%;

}



.productgrid  img{

    max-width:100%;
    display:block;
    padding-bottom: 8px;
    margin: 0 auto;
 }
```

HTML Code:

```
<div class="productgrid">
                 <img src="phonepics/sony/z5.jpg" >
                  <a href="single.html">Sony Xperia Z5  </a>
                 <h3>$123</h3>
                 <ul>
                    <button class="button"><span>Buy </span></button>
                 </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: one solution: http://codepen.io/vsync/pen/DpmnK

Answer (score 0):

Do not apply an explicit width or height to the image. Instead, give it:

```
max-width:100%;
max-height:100%;
```

And if You want to specify the width, then set `height: auto`

Comment: can You create a JsFiddle with just 2-3 images, so we can try to fix an existing problem with code?

Answer (score 0):

Take the image inside a div. Set div width and height as your requirement. Then set img width: 100%, height: auto.

HTML:

```
  <div class="productgrid">
      <div class="img-container">
             <img src="phonepics/sony/z5.jpg" >
      </div>
              <a href="single.html">Sony Xperia Z5  </a>
             <h3>$123</h3>
             <ul>
                <button class="button"><span>Buy </span></button>
             </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.img-container {
   width: 16px;
   height: 20px;
   margin: 0 auto;
 }   

.productgrid  img{
   width: 100%;
   height: auto;
}
```